# Authorization while querying ADB2C logs from LogAnalyticsWorkspace

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitor, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I have setup a LogAnalyticsWorkspace to fetch logs from Azure ADB2C, to do that I have followed this microsoft [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/azure-monitor)

Everything works fine, logs are getting to the workspace and from the Logs section I can query with no issues.

The problem occurs when I try to query those logs from my API, using Azure Monitor Query client library for .NET, I have the following code:

```
        string clientId = "X";//Obtained from the B2C tenant (App registration)
        string clientSecret = "X";//Obtained from the B2C tenant(App registration)
        string tenantId = "X";//Obtained from the B2C tenant(App registration)

        var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
        var client = new LogsQueryClient(credentials);

        var response = await client.QueryWorkspaceAsync(
            "MY_WORKSPACE_ID",//Obtained from the tenant where I have LogAnalytics workspace
            "AuditLogs",
            new QueryTimeRange(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)));
```

The error I am obtaining it's the following:

> Valid authentication was not provided
> Status: 401 (Unauthorized)
> ErrorCode: AuthorizationRequiredError
> Content:
> {"error":{"message":"Valid authentication was not provided","code":"AuthorizationRequiredError","correlationId":"X","innererror": {"code":"AuthorizationRequiredError","message":"Register resource provider 'Microsoft.Insights' for this subscription to enable this query"}}}

I have checked that Microsoft.insights it's registered in the subscription used in the LogAnalyticsWorkspace.

Any clue what can be the issue? or is there a different way I should use to authenticate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: To query Azure AD B2C logs from Log Analytics Workspace, you have to grant **Log Analytics API `Data.Read`** API permission, this API permission is not present in AD B2C tenant.

In the Azure AD B2C app only Microsoft Graph API permissions are supported not other permissions which are linked to subscription.

[image]

- Features of the subscription in your B2C tenant shouldn't be used.
- Hence as a workaround, create an Azure AD application in Azure AD tenant.

[image]

And assign **Log Analytics Reader** to the application:

[image]

***And make use of below c# code to access Log Analytics logs***

*For sample, I used the sample code to access Logs:*

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        string tenantId = "TenantID";
        string clientId = "ClientID";
        string clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
        string workspaceId = "WorkspaceID";
        
        var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
        var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://westus2.api.loganalytics.io/.default" }));

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token.Token}");

            var apiUrl = $"https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/{workspaceId}/query?";

            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {response.StatusCode} - {response.ReasonPhrase}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response @Rukmini. when you say "create an Azure AD application in Azure AD tenant", this application needs to be created in Microsoft Entra? under app registrations? I don't get where you create the app and where you assign the role later on

Comment: Yes the application must be created under Microsoft Entrance under app registrations and assign in Microsoft Id tenant not in b2c tenant

Comment: so I did this in the Microsoft Id tenant: 1) go to microsoft entra and create an application in App registrations 2) in api permissions I added and granted admin consent to Log Analytics API Data.Read permission. The step I don't know where you did is the "Add role assignment"

Comment: definetelly creating the app as you described helped, as I am now getting as error Status: 403 (Forbidden) ErrorCode: InsufficientAccessError. So I am just missing this last step, where do you perform the add role assignment? Thanks!

Comment: Go to Azure Portal -> Subscriptions -> Select your subscription -> Access Contron (IAM) -> Add -> Add role assignment -> Search Log Analytics Reader -> assign role to the application as described in the answer